# How to create SIGN UP and LOG IN with Jquery and CouchDb?

Tags: jquery, authentication, couchdb, mapreduce, couchapp

How to set up **couchDb** to perform **SignUp** and **LogIn**? Creating special database just for that, or giving evry document username and password. The goal is to retrieve custom document based on user/password. So if one has successful LogIn, couch loads his own document with data only for him! Is there a way to do validation on CouchDb based on user input in client-side, any ideas,examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a user login to a couchapp that has a reader role defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389379/how-does-a-user-login-to-a-couchapp-that-has-a-reader-role-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are very important questions, and coincidentally, somebody asked the question yesterday of [how to log in to a couchapp with private data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389379/how-does-a-user-login-to-a-couchapp-that-has-a-reader-role-defined/7396030#7396030).

For signup, I recommend the excellent book from O'Reilly: *CouchDB: The Definitive Guide* which is free online. It has a [chapter on users and security](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html).