# Couchapp with partial reader access

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

It would be very elegant to run a full couchapp on Cloudant, but is seems there is no way of creating a public login page while the rest of the database requires authentication.

Can I serve public pages without opening the entire database?

Thanks,
Mikkel

Comment: I'd think that would be a very expensive way to host a web site (compared to other options). https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/auth/

Comment: @WiredPrairie there is a trade-off, avoiding CORS (cross-domain) with CouchDB replication to cut the amount of hits needed by having the app in the same domain context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for CouchDB (see question [How does a user login to a couchapp that has a reader role defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389379/how-does-a-user-login-to-a-couchapp-that-has-a-reader-role-defined)) should also work in Cloudant.